# Pre-randomization before random forest training in Scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am getting a surprisingly significant performance boost (+10% cross-validation accuracy gain) with sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier just by virtue of pre-randomizing the training set. 
This is very puzzling to me, since 
(a) RandomForestClassifier supposedly randomized the training data anyway; and 
(b) Why would the order of example matter so much anyway?

Any words of wisdom?

Comment: If you could share the data/code. Community would be in better position to help you. It might be possible that you are making some mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same issue and posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436918/why-does-shuffling-training-data-affect-my-random-forest-classifiers-accuracy), which luckily got resolved.

In my case it's because the data are put in order, and I'm using K-fold cross-validation without shuffling when doing the test-train split. This means that **the model is only trained on a chunk of adjacent samples with certain pattern.**

An extreme example would be, if you have 50 rows of sample all of class A, followed by 50 rows of sample all of class B, and you manually do a train-test split right in the middle. The model is now trained with all samples of class A, but tested with all samples of class B, hence the test accuracy will be 0.

In scikit, the [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) do the shuffling by default, while the [KFold class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) doesn't. So you should do one of the following according to your context:

- Shuffle the data first
- Use train_test_split with shuffle=True (again, this is the default)
- Use KFold and remember to set shuffle=True

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of the examples should not affect RF performance at all. Note Rf performance can vary by 1-2% across runs anyway. Are you keeping cross-validation set separately before training?(Just ensuring this is not because cross-validation set is different every time). Also by randomizing I assume you mean changing the order of the examples.

Also you can check the Out of Bag accuracy of the classifier in both cases for the training set itself, you don't need a separate cross-validation set for RF.

During the training of Random Forest, the data for training each individual tree is obtained by sampling by replacement from the training data, thus each training sample is not used for roughly 1/3 of the trees. We can use the votes of these 1/3 trees to predict the out of box probability of the Random forest classification. Thus with OOB accuracy you just need a training set, and not validation or test data to predict performance on unseen data. Check Out of Bag error at https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm for further study.