# Why does shuffling training data affect my random forest classifier's accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, model, random-forest

The same question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423322/pre-randomization-before-random-forest-training-in-scikit-learn). But since the OP didn't post the code, not much helpful information was given.

I'm having basically the same problem, where for some reason shuffling data is making a big accuracy gain (from 45% to 94%!) to my random forest classifier. (In my case removing duplicates also affected the accuracy, but that may be a discussion for another day) Based on my understanding on how RF algorithm works, this really should not happen.

My data are merged from several files, each containing the same samples in the same order. For each sample, the first 3 columns are separate outputs, but currently I'm just focusing on the first output.

The merged data looks like this. The output (1st column) is ordered and unevenly distributed:
[image]

The shuffled data looks like this:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

TOTAL_OUTPUTS = 3

... (code for merging data and feature engineering)

to_compare = {
    "merged": merged,
    "merged shuffled": merged.sample(frac=1.0),
    "merged distinct": merged.drop_duplicates(),
    "merged distinct shuffled": merged.drop_duplicates().sample(frac=1.0)
}


params = {'n_estimators': 300,
          'max_depth': 15,
          'criterion': 'entropy',
          'max_features': 'sqrt'
          }

for name, data_to_compare in to_compare.items():
    features = data_to_compare.iloc[:, TOTAL_OUTPUTS:]
    y = data_to_compare.iloc[:, 0]
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(**params)
    scores = cross_val_score(rf, features, y, cv=3)
    print(name, scores.mean(), np.std(scores))
```

Output:

```
merged 0.44977727094363956 0.04442305341799508
merged shuffled 0.9431099584137672 0.0008679933736473513
merged distinct 0.44780773420479303 0.04365860091028133
merged distinct shuffled 0.8486519607843137 0.00042583049485598673
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unshuffled data you are using shows that values of certain features tend to be constant for some rows. This causes the forest to be weaker because all the individual tress composing it are weaker.

To see that, take an extreme reasoning; if one of the features is constant all along the data set (or if you use a chunk of this dataset where the feature is constant), then this feature brings nothing in entropy changes if selected. so this feature is never selected, and the tree underfits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't see how this answers my question: if the constant feature did exist and make the model weaker, how come shuffling data resolve the issue? Also, I'd like to reassure you that constant features do not exist in the data. These features are selected from over 700 features and I have manually checked that each feature provides reasonablly high info gain.

Comment: read carefully: my assumption is that some features are constant "over some rows", not all the time. The CV procedure will train the model over parts of the dataset. In these parts there are chances that some features are indeed constant if dataset is unshuffled. That creates weak trees, and weak forest.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I alway use KFold with shuffle=True and I have totally forgotten that the more naive cv= (some int) just "split" the data, not randomly choosing samples for training/testing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The real reason is that RF is a greedy algo, thus order of features matter

Comment: Well, agree to an extent, if you change "presented" to "sampled", because order itself doesn't matter either, all the features are tried and best is selected.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov your statement is incorrect. The cost function of RF is evaluated over the training dataset regardless of the order of features values (and also regardless of order of features themselves). Greediness is a different problem in the fact it might not find the optimal solution because of the step by step cost function minimization. Greedy or not, an algorithm that uses all dataset features values regardless of ordering wouldn't be affected.

Comment: Greediness is out of question already. RF is a bagged algo, this is why I said you may be right if you say order is importand for sampling.

Comment: RF is still a greedy algorithm, as a bagg of a greedy one.
The sampling order, if you want to use this term, is indeed what cause the accuracy issue, just as OP could validate by using Shuffle = True.

Comment: On a side note, I would be interested to know why the answer has been downvoted although the answer is correct and accepted ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223356/discussion-between-bluexm-and-sergey-bushmanov).